# Как вычислить ширину полосы прокрутки браузера?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Можно ли вычислить ширину полосы прокрутки браузера?

Comment: Можно, [(смотрите тот же вопрос на en.SO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382516/getting-scroll-bar-width-using-javascript) но не очень простым образом.

Comment: @PeterOlson, а это для всех браузеров сработает?

Comment: @Grundy Как мне кажется, да, для всех частоиспользуемых современных браузеров